# Exception while consuming Spring Web Service using spring-ws-core API

Tags: spring-integration, spring-ws

I am consuming Spring Web Service using Spring-ws-core API. But when I am getting error when Add following dependency in my project's pom.xml file :

```
<!-- SPRING WEB-SERVICE DEPEDENCY INJECTION -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

The exception details is as below :

```
 2015-08-07 03:12:15,097 ERROR | main | org.mortbay.log                                         | Nested in org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-config/netverifier-process-integration.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Class [org.springframework.integration.config.xml.IntegrationNamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration] does not implement the [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandler] interface: 
org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Class [org.springframework.integration.config.xml.IntegrationNamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration] does not implement the [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandler] interface
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.resolve(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:126) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1330) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1325) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at
```

Can anyone please help me to solve this issue ?

Comment: Probably a class loader issue; it looks like there might be two versions of spring-beans.xxx.jar on the classpath and loaded by different classloaders.